# WAI-ARIA HTML. How to force 2 divs to be read out as one?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I'm new to ARIA and I'm having trouble combining two divs (both just text) into one readout. The layout is an iOS like table with 2 text labels in one row. The idea is to readout the row as a whole as opposed to labels one by one. 
I have found the **aria-label** only works if the role is set (like button) but then you get extra words read out.
Anyone has an idea?

HTML example:

```
<div id="block">
  <div id="foo" class="half" style="float:left">Date of birth</div>
  <div id="bar" class="half" style="float:right">1/01/1970</div>
</div>
```

label 1 should read out: "Date of birth 1/01/1970".

Comment: Try using `span` instead and if required for visual representation add `display:block` for screen.

Comment: Elaborating on the above comment, web semantics are important when it comes to accessibility. With a `div` tag you are differentiating a region of the document. For your purposes you are looking for a *prasing* element. So a `span` may suit you better.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to make a difference. aria-label is still ignored.

Comment: Why do you need "aria-label" all of the information is available visually.

Comment: OK, I may be getting confused as you have no `aria-label` in the code you have supplied. I was under the impression you were using that as a work around. So what is `label 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me say that you really don't need to do this. Screen reader users are used to dealing with HTML structure like this and can get around it easily.

However, if you want to do this:

Create an offscreen style.

```
.offscreen {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then hide the visual content using `aria-hidden` and add an off screen text.

```
<div id="block">
  <div aria-hidden="true" id="foo" class="half" style="float:left">Date of birth</div>
  <div aria-hidden="true" id="bar" class="half" style="float:right">1/01/1970</div>
  <div class="offscreen">Date of birth: January 1, 1970</div>
</div>
```